# How do I make my discord js bot type in someones dms?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I want my bot to type in a specific users DMs but I am getting an error message
"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'startTyping' of undefined"

```
Client.on("typingStart", async function(channel, user) {

    if(openTicketsByChannelID[channel.id]){
        if(openTicketsByChannelID[channel.id].userID){
            let dmToTypeIn = Client.channels.cache.get(idOfTheUserIwantTheBotToStartTypingTo)
            console.log(dmToTypeIn)
            dmToTypeIn.startTyping();
        }

    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`User.createDM()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/User?scrollTo=createDM), if the user closed the DM channel before, [`User.dmChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/User?scrollTo=dmChannel) is `null`.

```js
const user = await client.users.fetch("user id");
const dmChannel = await user.createDM();
dmChannel.startTyping();
```

The `.createDM()` method creates by default a new DM channel between the client and the user if there is none in the client's cache already.

Answer (score 0):

`User`s have a [`dmChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/User?scrollTo=dmChannel) property. You can run `startTyping()` on that.

```js
//user is an instance of User
let dm = user.dmChannel
dm.startTyping()
```

Answer (score 0):

Update from the current version of discord.js
We are now using the `channel.sendTyping()` method instead of `startTyping()`